# Facial Expression recognition on Android Java using Tensorflow Lite

Tags: java, android, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I am working on facial expression recognition using deep learning algorithm i.e CNN, to identify user's emotions like happy, sad, anger etc. I have trained and tested it in python using pre-trained VGG-16 model altering top 3 layers to train my test images,To speed up the training process i have used Tensorflow. The test accuracy is 62%. I have saved architecture and weights of my model in train_model.h5 file.

Now i have to implement it on Android phone. For that i have used Tensorflow-Lite as it is suitable for android phone. So i had converted my .h5 file in .tflite file using Tensorflow lite converter method.

This is what i did for converting:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import lite
converter=lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file
            ("train_model.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open ("model.tflite" , "wb") .write(tflite_model)
```

I successfully got the tflite file.

Coming to android part i have chose Java language to load tflite file and predict the emotions of new image. I have gone through the example of "image classification" given in the Tensorflow-lite website, but i am confused how to use it. I don't know how to read tflite and use it to predict the output of new image and display the result on android app. Please help me with some good resources with explanation

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good blog post on how to use an image classification TFLite model on Android:
https://medium.com/tensorflow/using-tensorflow-lite-on-android-9bbc9cb7d69d

How you'll run inferences depends largely on how the model was built and what inputs it expects. If the approach in the blog post above doesn't work, you'll have to manually compose the tensor to feed to the model. The [code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/tflite/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifier.java) in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#0) does just that.

Another option to consider is the [face detection API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces) in ML Kit. It does some of what you are looking for (though not all of it) by detecting the curvature of the smile.

Comment: I got little bit idea. Thanks

Comment: Is there any improvement?